# How to parse nested list (with dash representing the depth of a node) in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a raw text with the following format:

```
   page 1
   -page 1.1
   --page 1.1.1
   page 2
   page 3
   -page 3.1
   page 4
```

I want to create nested database records (by using Ancestry gem) with
   the code like:

```
   previous_page_id = nil

   raw_text.split("\n").each do |page_title|
     p = Page.new(:title => page_title.gsub(/^\-*/, "")
     p.parent_id = previous_page_id

     p.save!

     previous_page_id = p.id
   end
```

This obviously doesn't work as expected, as the DB records should be:

- Page.find(2) should be the child of Page.find(1)
- Page.find(3) should be the child of page.find(2)
- Page.last should a root page

Can someone tell me how to parse it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested because I don't have the gem, but judging from your code, I think you want something like:

```
text = <<END
  page 1
   -page 1.1
   --page 1.1.1
   page 2
   page 3
   -page 3.1
   page 4
END

ancestors = []
text.each_line do |title|
    title.strip =~ /^(-*)(.*)$/
    depth = $1.length
    title = $2
    p = Page.new(title: title)
    ancestors.pop until ancestors.length <= depth
    p.parent_id = ancestors.last unless ancestors.empty?
    p.save!
    ancestors.push(p.id)
end
```

Comment: Thanks, but the execution of the code lasts forever, I don't really understand your code so I can't figure out what's wrong.

Comment: I don't have edit privileges but if I'm following it correctly the '+ 1' is the culprit. Remove that and it should work.